# How do I run java with command line arguments in VSCode?

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, package

My employer has given me access to a site that teaches many things (not sure if allowed to post the name or not). I have decided to try and learn Java. The way this site teaches it is through IntelliJ, but I have learned JavaScript, Python, Node, and React in VSCode, and I don't want to learn another system.

Through Google, I downloaded JDK 11, as well as the Java Extension Pack. I have had a few errors that I have been able to resolve, but I am now stuck on java App.java. Earlier in the day, I was able to make it work, but now when I try to run javac App.java and then java com.example.App, it's not found. Nothing I have tried has made it work. Maybe it only worked before I used Maven...can't remember.

On the topic of com.example.App, is there an easy way to create a package? Google says it's almost always needed to create a package. Only way I've figured out how to do that is with Maven, but the quickstart version is 1.7 or 8 (when I have 11). So I have to go into the POM and edit

```
  <properties>
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
```

to

```
  <properties>
<maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
```

Is there a way to create a package without using Maven?

I just realized that I haven't even explained my title. So on the site I'm learning Java, it says there's a way to use command line arguments, for example:

```
java com.example.App "I am an argument"
```

Since I can no longer run my code with java, I can not do that. If anyone can help, you'd be amazing!

Answer (score 1):

Q: *Is there a way to create a package without using Maven?*

I don’t see any direct relation between the two.

Packages are the logical grouping of classes in a folder structure in Java whereas Maven is just a Java build tool.

Yes, you can create packages without using Maven.

If you are using any IDE, for example VS Code you can always create packages as below:

1. Create a Maven based Java project. Maven projects have the following structure
   src/main/java (all your source code goes here) and src/main/test (unit test goes here) , src/main/resources(non java files goes here).
2. Initially  while creating the project you would have created a package with name com.example
3. To create a new package, right click and select New folder
4. Enter the folder name(this is your package name),for example "view".
5. Now you will have a new package com.example.vew. Similarly we can create packages at any folder level and place our Java file inside that.

Let me know if you this is good enough for you.